# Is there a cleaner way to enable markdown output in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, markdown

Using HAML in Rails, whenever I have a text field of some kind that I want the user to be able to easily format, I use HAML's markdown filter. In the template that looks like this:

```
.description
  :markdown
    #{folder.description}
```

This works, but I've never really liked it. If I didn't need markdown on this text field I would just be doing:

```
.description= folder.description
```

In some of my views there are many instances of text that can be markdown formatted, and it always breaks the flow of the template to insert them.

Is there any cleaner or simpler way to use markdown formatted text in a HAML template, or is there perhaps an alternative method of adding simple text formatting to a text field that results in cleaner template code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest a simple helper, something like:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def markdown(text)
  BlueCloth::new(text).to_html.xml_safe
end
alias :md :markdown

# app/views/folders/show.html.haml
.description= md folder.description
```

Comment: `xml_safe`? I got an error.  Using instead: `raw BlueCloth::new(text).to_html`

Answer (score 2):

When I have compilable formatting (whether it be markdown, or textile) I usually store both the html version, and the format version in the database.

So I would probably have `folder.description_markdown` and `folder.description_html` fields, and in a before_save on folder or some other appropriate location I would perform the markdown parsing there, and save the html value.

Then, in your view, all you would need is:

```
.description= raw folder.description_html
```

And if you have an edit page for the description you would make sure the text field is correctly editing the description_markdown field.

An example before_save callback I have right now to save Textile formatting is right here:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  # Note that the {attr}_changed? method is given to you
  # by ActiveRecord for every database field on your model.
  before_save :update_html, :if => :textile_changed?

  def convert_textile
    RedCloth.new(textile).to_html
  end

  protected
    def update_html
      self.html = convert_textile
    end
end
```

I feel like this makes the haml template easier to follow, and also reduces overhead from having to parse the markdown every time the field is retrieved.

Comment: Interesting idea... I'll test it out some!